# Can't get a response in JSON format, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, get, python-requests

I am trying to execute a get request to a service that can send responses in JSON or xml. In the header, I specify Content-Type 'application/json', but I get a response in xml format. I performed the same query using SOAP UI and received a JSON response.

Maybe something is wrong in my request?

```
import requests

myheader = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
auth = requests.get ("""myurl/authenticate""", auth=('user','password'), 
headers = myheader)

url = 'myurl/service'
req = requests.get(url = url,
                   header = myheader,
                   cookies=auth.cookies)
print(req.json)
print(req.text)
```

Error text on 'print(req.json)':
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Can you check if `req.text` (so the server response) contains valid JSON?

Comment: req.txt contains the answer in xml format, but I asked Content-Type 'application/json' in my request

Comment: in `requests.get` I think the kwarg is `headers` not `header`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by fixing header:
    myheader={'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}